# How does Sami use transparent background in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-web-designer

[image]

I want my background to be dark semi transparent, how can I do that? I have used this CSS in the image above `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.322), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.322));`

Comment: It looks like the background is semi transparent, thats what the grey is. `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.322);` would come out gray over a white background.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem.

Comment: Is Sami the answerer? 

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a linear gradient, try the following:

```
.some-selector {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Where the 0.5 is the percentage of opacity for the RGB color from 0 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

If it is  tag in html with 'scr' then you can use opacity..

```
img{
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

or if it has some class to  or class to parent  if you want to target specificly

```
.parent-class img.img-class{
   opacity: 0.5;  
}
```

where opacity = 1 is full visible and opacity = 0 in fully trans parent.

```css
 .parent {
        background: #ff6347;
      }
 .parent img.img-box {
        opacity: 0.5;
        height: 500px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <img
        class="img-box"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8299099/pexels-photo-8299099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
```